# Electron scattering. Relation between thermal and electrical properties

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, scattering

Let's restrict to elastic electron phonon scattering in metallic periodic crystals. Is the scattering mechanism responsible for electronic thermal conductivity/resistivity the same as for electrical conductivity/resistivity?

Comment: This is not actually an answer, but I think that if you have a basic understanding of quantum mechanics and calculus you can find the answer to this question, along with many other interesting stuff, in the first chapters of "Solid State Physics" by Ashcroft and Mermin.

Comment: It is not exactly the same. There are deviations from the Wiedemann-Franz law.